# Why the type errors are blocking the UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typeerror, create-react-app

I started a new create react app with typescript and for any type error, the ui is covered by this black screen showing errors, i want to see type errors only in terminal

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in src/App.tsx:10:45

TS2322: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
8 |       
9 |

> 10 |         <Route path="/product" element={hi}>
> |                                             ^^
> 11 |       
> 12 |     </>
> 13 |   );

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/495K0.png)

Any way to fix this?

Comment: IS should be a string instead of true. Try converting this attribute to a string ('true')

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Well for errors that prevent transpilation, it doesn't really matter if it's on the screen or in the console, either way the app won't run until they're fixed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using create-react-app,

1- If you want to ignore for whole project. Create a ".env" file in the root of the project and put inside it these settings.

```
TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR=true
ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true
```

2-If you want to ignore just that line. Just above the line put this comment.

```
// @ts-ignore
```